# How to filter RDD by attribute/key and then apply function using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, filter, rdd

I have some example data:

```py
my_data = [{'id': '001', 'name': 'Sam', 'class': "classA", 'age': 15, 'exam_score': 90},
           {'id': '002', 'name': 'Tom', 'class': "classA", 'age': 15, 'exam_score': 78},
           {'id': '003', 'name': 'Ben', 'class': "classB", 'age': 16, 'exam_score': 91},
           {'id': '004', 'name': 'Max', 'class': "classB", 'age': 16, 'exam_score': 76},
           {'id': '005', 'name': 'Ana', 'class': "classA", 'age': 15, 'exam_score': 88},
           {'id': '006', 'name': 'Ivy', 'class': "classA", 'age': 16, 'exam_score': 77},
           {'id': '007', 'name': 'Eva', 'class': "classB", 'age': 15, 'exam_score': 86},
           {'id': '008', 'name': 'Zoe', 'class': "classB", 'age': 16, 'exam_score': 89}]

my_rdd = sc.parallelize(my_data)
my_rdd
```

Let's say I have some simple function:

```py
def divide_by_100(value):
  return value/100
```

The goal is to divide all exam scores by 100 with the function, and then find the minimum score. My idea is to:

- filter my_rdd by key, such that that only values in `exam_score` remain
- apply the `divide_by_100()` function to this
- use the `.min()` and `.collect()` function to print the lowest exam score in the data

*I'm aware that `groupByKey()` could also be used.*

The problem is that I don't know how to put this into practice using `pyspark`. Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: `groupByKey`: Note If you are grouping in order to perform an aggregation (such as a sum or average) over each key, using `reduceByKey` or `aggregateByKey` will provide much better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the minium score without any keys:

```
score_rdd = my_rdd.map(lambda my_dict: my_dict['exam_score']/100)
print(score_rdd.min())
# 0.76
```

this is a solution using pyspark rdd:

```
score_rdd = my_rdd.map(lambda my_dict: (my_dict['class'], my_dict['exam_score']/100))
print(score_rdd.collect())
# [('classA', 0.9), ('classA', 0.78), ('classB', 0.91), ('classB', 0.76), ('classA', 0.88), ('classA', 0.77), ('classB', 0.86), ('classB', 0.89)]
from builtins import min # import python function: min
class_min_rdd = score_rdd.reduceByKey(min)
print(class_min_rdd.collect())
# [('classA', 0.77), ('classB', 0.76)]
```

this is a solution using pyspark dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = my_rdd.toDF()
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- age: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- class: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- exam_score: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
df = df.withColumn('score', col('exam_score')/100).groupBy('class').agg(min('score').alias('score'))
df.show(10, False)
# +------+-----+
# |class |score|
# +------+-----+
# |classB|0.76 |
# |classA|0.77 |
# +------+-----+
print(df.collect())
# [Row(class='classB', score=0.76), Row(class='classA', score=0.77)]
```

Comment: amazing!! I have one final question if you don't mind answering; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73244547/how-to-group-and-filter-rdd-to-return-a-small-summary-using-pyspark

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use collect or use RDD, use Dataframe instead

```
df = my_rdd.toDF()
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

from pyspark.sql.window import Window
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('class').orderBy('exam_score')
df1=df.withColumn("rank",rank().over(windowSpec))
w = Window.partitionBy('class')
df1.withColumn('minB', F.min('rank').over(w)).where(F.col('rank') == F.col('minB')).drop('minB').withColumn('exam_score',(df1.exam_score)/100).drop('rank').show()

+---+------+----------+---+----+
|age| class|exam_score| id|name|
+---+------+----------+---+----+
| 16|classB|      0.76|004| Max|
| 16|classA|      0.77|006| Ivy|
+---+------+----------+---+----+
```